# How to pass a secure token to a bash script?

Tags: bash, security

I need to pass a private token to a bash script `my-script.sh` that looks like this:

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=${TOKEN} -t my_image .
```

One way would be like `TOKEN=my-secure-token-here my-script.sh`, but the secret token can  then be revealed via the ./history command. What is a secure way to pass the token?

Comment: store it in a file, pass it with `$(cat file-holding-secret-token.txt)` ?

Comment: If the history is all you are concerned about, then have a look at [bash's `HISTIGNORE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html).